# Is there a terminal command to find the path of libraries I installed with "brew install"?

Tags: terminal, pythonbrew

Is there a terminal command to see the location of libraries I installed with `brew install`? I know they are in `/usr/local`, but I would like to see the whole path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for which. For example:

```
which brew
# /usr/local/bin/brew

which pod
# /usr/bin/pod
```

Comment: Thanks @donnywals but `which` is not exactly what I'm looking. it doesn't work for all libraries I had previously installed. For example, I installed the CImg library but when I type `which CImg`, nothing is returned. Yet, it's located in `/usr/local/Cellar/cimg/1.6.1/include`

Comment: I found what I was looking for. It was `brew info`